# Android Tab change based on spinner selection

Tags: android, tabs, spinner

I'm currently trying to set my tabs to change based on my spinner selection any code Ideas??? I just figure this out. This is where I'm stuck at I have everything else setup for my tabhost

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
        long id) {

    switch (pos) {
    case (1):

        Intent a = new Intent(this, YahooAct.class);
    startActivity(a);

        break;
    }
```